# Does "integrability condition" have a specific meaning or is it used in a casual way?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

The following is an excerpt from Marco Gualtieri's [thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401221)

> A central theme of this thesis is that classical geometrical
> structures which appear, at first glance, to be completely different
> in nature, may actually be special cases of a more general unifying
> structure. Of course, there is wide scope for such generalization, as
> we may consider structures defined by sections of any number of
> natural bundles present on manifolds. What must direct us in deciding
> which tensor structures to study is the presence of natural
> integrability conditions.

> Good examples of such conditions include the
> closure of a symplectic form, the Einstein or special holonomy
> constraint on a Riemannian metric, the vanishing of the Nijenhuis
> tensor of a complex structure, and the Jacobi identity for a Poisson
> bivector, among many others.

I think by closure of symplectic form, it means $d\omega=0$.

The only notion of integrability I know is integrability of a subbundle of $TM$; that is, for every point of $M$, there is an integrable manifold corresponding to the distribution.

Frobenius theorem says $L\subseteq TM$ is integrable if and only if $[X,Y]\in L$ for every $X,Y\in L$.

But, I do not fully understand what is "integrable" in a differential form being closed, or a bivector to satisfy Jacobi identity or for Nijenhuis tensor to be zero.

I would understand if we call it "a smoothly varying condition" or something similar, but, why would some one want to refer them as integrability conditions?

Comment: Specific meaning; see also his Annals paper: https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2011/174-1/p03

Comment: I did not mean about his paper alone. That was only to give an example..In general people use the phrase integrability  conditions to mean something in different contexts. So, I wanted to ask if there is a universal meaning for that phrase or if it varies depending on the situation.. I understand what integrability conditions he is talking about. I am having difficulty with terminology, not the concept..

Comment: There is a whole theory of $G$-structures and their integrability.

Comment: https://www.few.vu.nl/~pasquott/course16.pdf

Comment: @ThomasRot Thank you.  It looks like, all the structures over $M$ mentioned in the question is a $G$-structure on $M$ for some appropriate Lie group $G$.. Theorem 2.31 (Newlander-Nirenberg)) says an almost complex structure (when seen as a $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ structure) is integrable if and only if Nij tensor vanishes.. It says "Proof. too difficult to give here." :D

Comment: @ThomasRot This notes will be in my reading list. I like the way it is written. Too good it is :) I do not fully understand but I will be able to after spending some time..

Comment: You should have a look at def 2.4

Comment: @ThomasRot Yes, I saw that definition. It says about when a G-structure is called integrable. I mean to say I do understand the formal idea but to really digest I need some time..

Comment: Integrability of $G$-structures is a special case of the Frobenius theorem, if they are of finite type. But for infinite type $G$-structures, the two notions are quite different. In general (and in these cases), integrability conditions mean conditions required to establish existence of local or formal solutions of systems of partial differential equations, as in the setting of the theory of exterior differential systems.

Comment: @BenMcKay Ok. I do not know about exterior differential systems. I will see about that. thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there is a well defined notion of integrability of a G-structure on a manifold.

Thanks to the user Thomas Rot who has given the reference [Linear $G$-structures by examples](https://www.few.vu.nl/%7Epasquott/course16.pdf)

Definition $2.1$ is that of $G$-structure on a manifold M.

It defines the notion of integrability of a $G$-structure in Definition $2.4$.

1. A ($p$-dimensional) distribution $\mathcal{F}$ on a ($n$-dimensional) manifold $M$ can be seen as a $GL(p,n-p)$ structure on the manifold $M$. We can talk about integrability of this $G$-structure. It says (Theorem $2.25$) $\mathcal{F}$ is involutive if and only if $\mathcal{F}$ is an integrable G-structure. This goes by the name Frobenius theorem.
2. An almost complex structure J on a manifold $M$ (of dimension $2k$) can be seen as a $GL_k(\mathbb{C})$-structure on the manifold $M$. We can talk about integrability of this $G$-structure. It says that (Theorem $2.31$) Nijenhuis tensor of $J$ vanishes if and only if $J$ is an integrable $G$-structure. This goes by the name Newlander-Nirenberg theorem.
3. A non degenerate $2$-form $\omega$ on a manifold $M$ (of dimension $2k$) can be seen as a $Sp_k(\mathbb{R})$-structure on the manifold $M$. We can talk about integrability of this $G$-structure. It says (Theorem $2.41$) $\omega$ is closed if and only if $\omega$ is an integrable $G$-structure. This goes by the name of Darboux theorem.